# Motivation behind GARCH

Tags: time-series, forecasting, estimation, arima, garch

Suppose I have built an ARIMA model for a real life process, where volatility is present.
Now if for modelling the ARCH effect I fit a GARCH model, how will it affect my ARIMA model in terms of prediction and in terms of fitting procedure?

Comment: If you find an earlier thread that answers your questions, please flag your own post or notify us otherwise so that we can close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Forecasting two part ARIMA-GARCH model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/488753/forecasting-two-part-arima-garch-model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been discussed on Cross Validated before. You may start [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=arima+garch+estimation).

The short answer is, if you fit the ARIMA-GARCH model simultaneously, you will get different parameter estimates of the ARIMA model than if you fit ARIMA alone (and possibly GARCH afterwards). As a result, the estimated conditional mean at a future time point (which people usually take as their point forecast for that time point) will be different. In addition, the GARCH part will make the spread of the forecast density (governed by the conditional variance) vary over time.